# Made Custom Post Types, but single.php not working

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, single

I made some Custom Post Types, filled them up with some posts, added the template tags to the templates.

The problem now is that whenever I click the 'Read More' button on a custom post type (the_permalink()), it doesn't show the singlepage. It shows the homepage.

I've created a single.php file and a single-smoelenboek.php file, it should go to 1 of those 2.

I've also flushed by clicking the 'Save' button in settings -> permalinks.

Permalinks are on Post Name right now, I them around a bit, but it didn't matter.

**The Custom Post Type**

```
    function smoelenboek() {
    $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Smoelenboek Sectie', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Smoelenboek Sectie', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Smoelenboek Sectie', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Smoelenboek Sectie', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Smoelenboek item toevoegen', 'content', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Voeg een nieuwe Smoelenboek item toe', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'Nieuwe Smoelenboek item', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Bewerk Smoelenboek item', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'Bekijk Smoelenboek item', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'Alle Smoelenboek items', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Zoek Smoelenboek items', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Hoofd Smoelenboek items', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'Geen Smoelenboek items gevonden', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Geen Smoelenboek items gevonden in prullenbak', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
    'label' => __('smoelenboek'),
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => false,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'smoelenboek' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => false,
    'hierarchical'       => true,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'revisions','post-formats' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'smoelenboek', $args );
    }

add_action( 'admin_init', 'smoelenboek' );
```

**The Section**

```
<?php $options = get_option( 'custom_voorpagina_panel_smoelenboek' );  ?>
<section id="smoelenboek">
<div class="container persoon-wrapper">
<h1> <?php echo $options['smoelenboek-titel']; ?> </h1>
<h3> <?php echo $options['smoelenboek-sub-titel']; ?> </h3>

<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(
array(
'post_type' => 'smoelenboek', 
'posts_per_page' => 4
)
);
while($loop->have_posts()):
$loop->the_post();
$thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id());

?>

<div class="persoon">
<?php 

$image = get_field('afbeelding');

if( !empty($image) ): 


// thumbnail
$size = 'products_thumb';
$thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
$width = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-width' ];
$height = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-height' ];

?>

<img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>">
<div class="wrapper">
<h3> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> <?php the_field('button_tekst') ?></a>
</div>
</div>
<?php
endif;
endwhile;
?>  
</div>   

<div class="meer-personen container">
<a href="/"> <?php echo $options['smoelenboek-bekijk-meer']; ?> </a>
</div>

</section>
```

**Conclusion:** Created custom post type, single page of custom post type not working. It would be nice if someone could help me with this.

**EDIT:** also single-smoelenboek.php is not working. 
**EDIT 2:** /hello-world works. Picks up the single.php perfectly fine.

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Please, add all the relevant code to the question itself. The question and its answer must be useful on its own without relying on external services, specially if the external services just display code. Imaging that the external sevice goes down: the question will be almost totally useless.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, code would mess up.

Comment: You can try this solution . Change your permalinks from admin panel and then check your post page .

Comment: Write the code, use `{}` button in the editor and you will have the code indented and preformatted.

Comment: @cybmeta Yeah I tried that, it will only dispay the first line as code, rest will be plain text.

Comment: @cybmeta Alright, there you go.. It didn't work because of the indenting of my code in the file.

Comment: Do the read more links have the URLs you expect in their src attributes or do they actually link to the home page?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook The url goes straight to the post. Shouldn't it be /smoelenboek/*post*? Right now it's just *post*. I tried a lot of combinations though. They all return the homepage template.

Comment: The permalinks should be /smoelenboek/*posts*
Do you have any redirect rules active?
Also on a side note where did you hook the function `smoelenboek`

Comment: Try changing your rewrite parameter to `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'smoelenboek','with_front' => false),` and saving your permalink settings again to flush the rewrite rules.

Comment: @bagpipper No redirects, and I hooked the function above the function: 
add_action( 'admin_init', 'smoelenboek' );

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook That did not work :(

Comment: Your hook is wrong.  Use `init`.  `admin-init` only fires on admin screens.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook Oh wow. That worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please, @AndyMacaulay-Brook, post it as an answer, so Frisidan can mark the answer and other users with the same problem can find the solution easily.

Comment: Already on it - I've spent my weekend going through old posts and adding the same nag :-)

Comment: @Frisidan always `init`  is only hook your post types use `admin_init` only for sections which are specific to admin I should have guessed you used `admin_init` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `admin-init` hook only fires on admin screens.  The correct hook to use for registering post types is `init`.

So change:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'smoelenboek' );
```

... to ...

```
add_action( 'init', 'smoelenboek' );
```

... and flush your rewrite rules once (save permalink settings in admin) and all should be well.

Comment: No problem - glad it's working for you.